# How to override a file in Portfolio?

Tags: marketing-cloud, content, upload

I had uploaded a CSS file, and then I modified it on local, so I need to replace the old one by upload latest one. But when I selected override and uploaded it, the css is still keep the old version. I have tried do that again but nothing is works.

Is anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a 10-15 minute refresh time delay on all portfolio items. If you give it time, the document will refresh to the new version. Please make sure to clear your cache as well to ensure you are not viewing the cached version instead of the live version.

Comment: Hum, you`re right, it`s cache......

Comment: Please remember to mark as answer if this solved your issue.